# how to access textbox value from another webpage in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i want to display text box value to another text box from one webpage to another in a button click.
i know the windows code But don't know the web application.

```
public qus as form = new question()

qus.txtname=txtname.text
```

Comment: make use of session or querystring

Answer (score 2):

On first page add button click event

```
Sub Btn_Click(sender As Object, _
                      e As EventArgs)

        Response.Redirect("SecondPage.aspx?id=" + txtname.text, false)

End Sub
```

on second page set your text on page load.

```
Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   If Not IsPostBack
      SecondPageTextBox.Text = Request.QueryString("textValue").ToString()
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the query string to pass the text value to other page in the button click handler, like this:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Response.Redirect("OtherPage.aspx?textValue='Value from other page'")
End Sub
```

Now in the `Page_Load` of the other page, pull the query string value out and assign it to the text box, like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If Request.QueryString("textValue") IsNot Nothing Then
        YourTextBox.Text = Request.QueryString("textValue").ToString()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write code on first page

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Response.Redirect("webpage2.aspx?textValue='value'")
End Sub
```

On second page

```
Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   If Not IsPostBack
      SecondPageTextBox.Text = Request.QueryString("textValue").ToString()
   End If
End Sub
```